# QT - overriding QToolButton paint event

Tags: qt

I have own widget MyToolButton which inherit from `QToolButton`. In paintEvent I want draw only "background" from original `QToolButton`. I mean, I need draw only style (clicked, hover, etc) but without text and image. These things I want draw by my self (with custom formatting etc). When I call `QToolButton::paintEvent(ev)` then everything is painted. How to exclude image and text from painting? I supose that I should use `drawControl()`, `drawPrimitive()` and `drawComplexControl()` but can't understands all these states

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source code of `void QToolButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` is:

```
QStylePainter p(this);
QStyleOptionToolButton opt;
initStyleOption(&opt);
p.drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ToolButton, opt);
```

`QStylePainter::drawComplexControl` calls `QStyle::drawComplexControl`, which is a pure virtual function, and its implementation depends on a style, you are using. What you need is to go to a source code of concrete impementation (like `QWindowsXPStyle` or `QGtkStyle`), find `drawComplexControl()` implementation and use it in your `paintEvent`. For a simple control like `QPushButton`, you can easy rewrite its drawing quite style-independently. Redrawing `QToolButton` would be a bit more tricky task.
A good choice would be using source code of `QCommonStyle`.

Comment: How did you found source? I'm newbie in QT, when I go to header declaration by CTRL+click, F4 doesn't load .cpp

Comment: It depends on OS you are using and type of Qt installation. When using Qt libraries for Windows, source can be found in %QT_HOME%/src. When using deb-based linux and its repositories you can download source with command "apt-get source qt4-x11". And finaly in any system you can always download it from here: http://releases.qt-project.org/qt4/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4.tar.gz

Comment: Fix: not %QT_HOME%/src - but %QTDIR%/src

Comment: Thanks. I have debian installation so I must download it. Then I will check how it is drawed